# Can I create a bar (column) chart in Openpyxl from "horizontal" data?

Tags: python, charts, openpyxl

I have been using [this guide](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/openpyxl/stable/openpyxl.pdf) as my chief resource for creating charts using openpyxl.  All of the examples there appear to be of the form:

HEADER1 HEADER 2 HEADER 3
X1      Y11      Y12
X2      Y12      Y22
.....

So the categories would be the first column and the data series would be the other columns.  What I am wondering about is can we work with data like this?

X1 X2 X3 ...
Y11 Y12 Y13
Y21 Y22 Y23

It would appear that no matter what I set as may categories (in the following code) that openpyxl tries to tell me that my data is laid out in the first manner.  Note that this code is called 5 times and a typical col/row set of values for a chart is:

min_row = 3
max_row = 3
min_col = 6
max_col = 27

```
    if draw_charts == True:
        chart = BarChart()
        chart.type = "col"
        chart.style = 10
        chart.title = "Channel " + str(channel_name) + " Stdevs " + str(stdevs)
        chart.x_axis.title = 'Time Diff (s)'
        chart.y_axis.title = 'Counts'

        values = Reference(ws2, min_col = 6, min_row = 3 + index * 2, max_col = 5 + bins, max_row=3 + index * 2)
        categories = Reference(ws2, min_col=6, min_row = 2 + index * 2, max_col = 5 + bins, max_row=2 + index * 2)
        chart.add_data(values, titles_from_data=True)
        chart.set_categories(categories)
        ws2.add_chart(chart, num2col(col2num('A') + index * 6) + '22')
```

Comment: What's `col2num`? You probably want to use something from `utils`. And avoid lots of implicit string concatenations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add_data()` takes a `from_rows` parameter with the default as `False`.

Comment: Yep, I guess I missed that somewhere.  Thanks!  That is such a times savings because it will eliminate me having to edit the charts after the spreadsheet has been produced.

Comment: The chart docs aren't complete, especially when it comes to the more low level functions. Series are intelligent to know whether they refer to rows or columns.